# Config element \"FrameworkDataImageContentInterface\" is not declared in GraphQL schema

Tags: magento2, apollo-client, vue-storefront

This is error appeared when calling productDetail Apollo Client. Anyone know how to solve it?

Request

```
{"sku":{"eq":"1-VIRO-Classic-Non-quilted-4-inch"}},"configurations":\[\]},{"productDetail":"productDetail"},{}\]
```

Response:

```
{
    "name": "ApolloError",
    "graphQLErrors": [],
    "clientErrors": [],
    "networkError": {
        "name": "ServerError",
        "response": {
            "size": 0,
            "timeout": 0
        },
        "statusCode": 500,
        "result": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "debugMessage": "Config element \"FrameworkDataImageContentInterface\" is not declared in GraphQL schema",
                    "message": "Internal server error",
                    "extensions": {
                        "category": "internal"
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "message": "Response not successful: Received status code 500",
    "errors": [],
    "data": null
}
```

the expected result should show me detail product detail.